# .htaccess removing slashes in url

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7

I am working with drupal 7. Facing strange issue. Url redirect automatically removing slash from url.
`www.example.org/types-one-conditions`
After redirect its showing
`https://www.example.orgtypes-one-conditions`

Where I am doing wrong.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess by editing your question? Try testing from a new browser.